# Debugging Content Scripts for Chrome Extension

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

### General Questions

Hello! I'm delving into the world of Chrome Extensions and am having some problems getting the overall workflow down. It seems that Google has recently switched to heavily advocating Event Pages instead of keeping everything in background.js and background.html. I take part of this to mean that we should pass off most of your extension logic to a content script.

In [Google's Event Page primer](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), they have the content script listed in the manifest.json file. But in their event page example extension, it is brought in via this code block in background.js: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}, function() { });`

What are the advantages of doing it one way over the other?

### My Code

I'm going forward with the programatic way of injecting the content script, like Google's example.

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Let's get this sucker working",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    console.log("alert from background.js");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery-2.0.2.min.js"}, function() {
        console.log("jquery Loaded");
    });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"}, function() {
        console.log("content loaded");
    });
});
```

#### content.js

```
console.log('you\'r in the world of content.js');
var ans = {};

ans.createSidebar = function() {

    return {
        init: function(){
            alert("why hello there");
        }
    }
}();

ans.createSidebar.init();
```

I am able to get the first 3 `console.log` statements to show up in the background page's debugger. I'm also able to get the alert from content.js to show up in any website. But I'm not able to see the `console.log` from content.js, nor am I able to view any of the JS from content.js. I've tried looking in the "content scripts" section of the background page debugger's Sources tab. A few other posts on SO have suggested adding `debugger;` statements to get it to show, but I'm not having any luck with anything. The closest solution I've seen is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577330/unable-to-view-content-script-references-in-the-developer-tools-window), but is done by listing the content script in the manifest.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question solved my problem. By injecting content script through the manifest, I was not able to interact with the webpage's DOM in a true sense. Now, loading contentScript through browser_action solved my issue. Thanks. Appreciated.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Content scripts' console.log messages are shown in the web page's console instead of the background page's inspector.

Adding `debugger;` works if the Developer Tool (for the web page where your content script is injected) is opened.

Therefore, in this case, you should first activate the Developer Tool (of the web page) before clicking the browser action icon and everything should work just fine.

Comment: Excellent, that works! Is the `debugger;` statement always needed to get the debugger to recognize content scripts in the extension environment? It seems like you get one pass to make breakpoints. Any subsequent times you try to run the extension, the content scripts are loaded into a new environment and you lose your original breakpoints.

Comment: Debugger will persist page loads and will always break if you have the Developer Tool (F12) open. They are hard coded into your script, so don't forget to remove them later. Debugger will work on any javascript, they are not exclusive to content-scripts.

Comment: If the content script has errors such as mismatched brackets (eg. forgetting to close `)` after passing an inline function as an argument), no error is given and it fails silently even with `debugger`. This is really frustrating. How can you debug this?

Comment: where do you put "debugger;"  in background.js or contextscript.js?  Where exactly?

Comment: So adding a `debugger;` on is the only way to be able to view the `console.log` statements?

Comment: Adding `debgger;`.. _where_? A full log statement example wouldn't hurt

Comment: The debugger should be added within the content script file

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use the `debugger`method, but it doesn't not work well because the project is using `require.js` to bundle javascript files.

If you are also using `require.js` for chrome extension development, you can try adding something like [this](https://github.com/nonowarn/content-script-with-requirejs/blob/master/lib/require-cs.js) to the code base, AND change `eval(xhr.responseText)` to `eval(xhr.responseText + "\n//@ sourceURL=" + url);`. (like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732017/trouble-debugging-content-scripts-in-a-chrome-extension-using-require-js))

Then you can see the source file in your dev tool (but not the background html window)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Accessing it via the service worker (`background.js`)
2. Using `console.log()` (recommended)

The easiest as you may guess correctly is option 2 and is the recommended solution on [Google Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_debugging/#debug_cs)

To get this to work you have to inspect the current page you are running the `content.js` script and not the popup or background element.

Here's an example:

```js
// content.js
console.log('Hello World!');
```

In `matches:` key, specify the URL you want to run the script. You can use `["<all_urls>"]` to inject the script on all permitted URLs.

```js
// manifest.json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Now when you visit **google.com** and inspect the console, you'll see the "Hello World" string.

Answer (score 0):

### manifest v3

You can add `console.log` statements to your content scripts.

This is one of the best ways to debug an application.

Let's say you want to access a DOM node from the content script.

```
const node = document.querySelector("selector")
```

node will be `Element instance` if it exists else it will be `null`

If you can see the node in the Elements tab but not able to access it via content script then the node might have not been loaded at the time you accessed it.

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917682/14853666) to fix this issue.